# Detect all incidences of "Parameter was used more than once" in Pl/pgSQL functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm moving my database from a 8.4 server to a new 9.1 one.

Restoring a 8.4 copy in the 9.1 server throws no errors, but once I start using my plpgsql functions I've been hit with the 'Parameter was used more than once' error, it seems 9.1 doesn't allow the same name to be used both as IN and OUT, e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sales_tax(IN total int, OUT total int)
```

is allowed in 8.4 but not in 9.1. Using the same name was not intentional, I usually define for the same objet *param if its IN and param* if its out, but sometimes you miss where the underscore goes.

I've tried using pg_restore v8.4 and pg_restore v9.1, and even made the restore over an empty database but it never throws an error `@CREATE FUNCTION`, it's not being 'evaluated' at restore time as it is if you try to create a new func in 9.1 with duplicate param names.

So my question is, is there any easy script you can think of that could find all my non-compatible 9.1 functions?

I can't go one by one, there are too many.

Comment: There are internal postgres tables/view that store function names/parameters/bodies... Have you checked if it is possible to solve your problem with this tables?

Comment: FWIW, you want single `INOUT` parameters, but I think you've figured that out and just need to identify all the incidences that need changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query to the system catalog [**`pg_proc`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-proc.html) reports all functions with duplicated parameter names (one row per duplicated name):

```
SELECT proname, pg_get_function_identity_arguments(oid) AS f_identity_arguments
     , arg, count(*) AS ct
FROM   pg_proc p
      ,unnest(p.proargnames) arg
GROUP  BY oid, proname, arg
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER  BY 1, 2, ct DESC;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3690)

**Notably**, there is *one* built-in Postgres function featuring a duplicate parameter name: [`pg_stat_get_activity`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-FUNCS-TABLE). Don't touch this one.

This oddity has been raised before and Daniel provided some explanation:

- [PostgreSQL function with duplicate parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921510/postgresql-function-with-duplicate-parameters)

<sub>I really think this should be fixed. Even if it doesn't cause harm, it's a bad example and confusing.</sub>

Comment: Thks for taking your time answering, but I ended testing and fixing all my Functions one by one :)